# I want to know full flow of how snort processes a packet?

Tags: linux, snort

I know how to configure and run snort with dynamic rules written.

I know some stages of processing like decoding, preprocessors, dynamic rules match, output plugins etc.

I am using snort as inline mode.
I want to know full flow of processing from packet comes to snort and to packet is delivered to application.

Can any one suggest me a link like its complete flow description?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Slide 9 on this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/mboman/snort gives some information and page 45 in this pdf http://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/157870281X.pdf should also help.